# Error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError en usar mapas de google en SDK 28

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-pie

Acabo de actualizar SDK para Android Pie (28) y me encuentro que en `debug` todo funciona bien, a la hora de pasar a `release`, en una actividad que uso los mapas de google me devuelve el siguiente error

```
2018-10-10 11:26:21.673 5902-5946/app.montserratguide.pro E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-4
    Process: app.montserratguide.pro, PID: 5902
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/ProtocolVersion;
        at el.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@12862026@12.8.62 (040700-199405334):3)
        at ek.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@12862026@12.8.62 (040700-199405334):4)
        at em.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@12862026@12.8.62 (040700-199405334):51)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.ap.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@12862026@12.8.62 (040700-199405334):11)
        at dw.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@12862026@12.8.62 (040700-199405334):16)
        at dw.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@12862026@12.8.62 (040700-199405334):61)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.http.ProtocolVersion" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/app_chimera/m/MapsDynamite.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000006/MapsDynamite.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at ad.loadClass(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamiteloader@12862026@12.8.62 (040700-199405334):25)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at el.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@12862026@12.8.62 (040700-199405334):3) 
        at ek.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@12862026@12.8.62 (040700-199405334):4) 
        at em.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@12862026@12.8.62 (040700-199405334):51) 
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.ap.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@12862026@12.8.62 (040700-199405334):11) 
        at dw.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@12862026@12.8.62 (040700-199405334):16) 
        at dw.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@12862026@12.8.62 (040700-199405334):61)
```

Lo he probado en emulador, ya que no dispongo de un dispositivo físico con Android P (28)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buscando por [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50782806/android-google-maps-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-failed-resolution-of-lorg-a/50794266#50794266) he encontrado la solución:

en `AndroidManifest.xml` añadir dentro del bloque

```
<Application ..>
    <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
</>
```